# ERROR backtype.storm.event - Error when processing event java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Tags: java, apache-storm

My Storm version is 0.8.1 (same problem in 0.9.0.1)，Java Version: 1.6.0_26. How Can I solve this problem?I also find the same problem in
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/Wo5-SqGiQG4

```
[Thread-5] ERROR backtype.storm.event - Error when processing event java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:88) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor4.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor(Reflector.java:180) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.util$zip_contains_dir_QMARK_.invoke(util.clj:727) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$resources_jar$fn__6333.invoke(supervisor.clj:436) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.core$filter$fn__4106.invoke(core.clj:2480) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:67) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.first(LazySeq.java:82) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.RT.first(RT.java:566) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.core$first.invoke(core.clj:55) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$resources_jar.invoke(supervisor.clj:434) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__6338.invoke(supervisor.clj:444) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:172) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$mk_synchronize_supervisor$this__6251.invoke(supervisor.clj:290) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__3072.invoke(event.clj:24) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_26]
```

Comment: Can't help without checking your source code or at least the important parts

Comment: I Just Run the https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter storm.starter.ExclamationTopology .And hava the same problem in every case